# Make AJAX call wait for event in php

Tags: php, ajax, synchronization, xmlhttprequest

I do not know if my tile line is clear enough... My problem is:
I have a JS application that needs to wait for an event on the server. At the moment it polls continuous the server data via XMLHttpRequest every second.

What I am thinking about is: Is it possible to make the call wait until for example a variable in PHP changes?

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) (colloquially known as Comet). There are many examples on SO and elsewhere.

- http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/
- [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)
- http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/long-polling-example-with-nodejs
- http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the right keyword and your last link will help me on developing my app. Thx!

Comment: Worth noting that php is very inefficient way to wait for an event. Also, can timeout after a minute or two depending on server configuration. Better to use node.js as a server if that is possible as it is event based, so does not waste processor whilst waiting for event.