# how to check if database is updated with php and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, chat

**I am making a chat box, everything is working fine, except the update thing.**
I am currently refreshing the page every 3 sec to check any new messages, but it will surely cause a massive load on server and is not elegant.

What i want is, chat box will check for new messages only when database is updated, rather than the timer of checking database after every 3 sec

Comment: instead of ajax you can use websockets

Answer (score 6):

You want AJAX push (server sends update to client only when there's something new). See an example here: http://provatosys.com/bid.html

Something like this would elaborate the request from the client:

```
function sendRequest(uid){
    var xmlhttp;
    var myUserId="";
    myUserId=uid;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            displayInChat(xmlhttp.responseText)//do stuff (process response, display message)
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","process_request.php?userid="+uid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    setTimeout("sendRequest("+uid+")",1000); //poll every second
}
```

Now you want to delay the reply from your server (process_request.php) until there's something to send (using something like `while (($msg=new_msgs()) === false) {sleep(timeout);}` for example) or the request times out and a new poll is send from the client (`setTimeout("sendRequest("+uid+")",timeoutinmillisecs);`). This is called Long polling and for applications like chats is more efficient than replying with an empty response.

You can find more info here: [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

and here: [Make AJAX call wait for event in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088051/make-ajax-call-wait-for-event-in-php)

and here: [Comet (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

**[EDIT]** *As a very much needed and more efficient alternative to long polling, now all major browsers support [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). The [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) has entered the status of (proposed) standard in 2011 (which means it has exited draft status and hasn't had any changes since). The best implementation in PHP is probably [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (as far as I know [the most up to date](http://socketo.me/reports/ab/index.html) with the standard by far). Here is a tutorial on how to build a web chat using it: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world*

Comment: I never knew about this (although I suspected it existed). Good answer! Do you have a link to documentation/tutorial on its usage/implementation?

Comment: i also understand it, ajax push is what i need, but not able to find a tutorial on how to implement it, any link or tutorial ?

Comment: Well you can use any packaged solution, like APE http://www.ape-project.org/ or start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29 (there are also some fancy alternatives like HTML5 websockets listed there), or just examing the code on the example and go by yourself from there (that's what I did some time ago, and I remember it as pretty straight forward :))